# Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types

Tags: sql, linq

```cs
var dbHold1 = _context.CompanyDirectorSh.Select(x => new { x.Shareholderid, Fname= x.Fname, Lname = x.Lname , x.Cmpid })
    .Union(_context.CompanyNonDirectorSh.Select(x => new { x.Shareholderid, Fname = x.Fname , Lname = x.Lname , x.Cmpid }))
    .Union(_context.CompanyAnotherCompany.Select(x => new { x.Shareholderid, Fname = x.ExecuterFname , Lname = x.ExecuterLname, x.Cmpid }))
    .Where(x => x.Cmpid == companyId).ToList();
```

Comment: It is still a bug: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129

Comment: Hi Svy  thanks for your comment and reference to the link, yes i found that issues ,and also able to work around by one of suggestino by converting conver.tostring .